# I don't understand why error shows "can't find module"?

Tags: node.js

app.js

```
var http = require('http');
const module1 = require('./module1');

function onRequest(request,response){
    response.writeHead(200,{'Content-type': 'text/plain'});
    response.write(module1.myStr);
    //module1.myfun();
    response.end();

}
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8000);
```

module1.js

```
function myfun(){
    console.log("fun is called");
}

var myStr = 'String!!'


module.exports.myfun = myfun;
module.exports.myStr = myStr;
```

I have followed nodejs basic tutorial by academind and wrote down the exact same code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Whether 2 files are in same directory??

Comment: What is your file structure

Comment: Please check if app.js and module1.js are in the same folder. I just ran your code and it works as expected. I did not get an error

Comment: I've just copy/pasted your code on my computer. It runs without any error.

Comment: yes , they were in the same directory

Answer (score -1):

You can try this one. also both file should be in same folder

**app.js**

```
var http = require('http');
const module1 = require('./module1');

function onRequest(request,response){
    response.writeHead(200,{'Content-type': 'text/plain'});
    response.write(module1.myStr);
    //module1.myfun();
    response.end();

}
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8000);
```

**module1.js**

```
function myfun() {
  console.log("fun is called");
}


var myStr = "String!!";

module.exports.myfun = myfun;
module.exports.myStr = myStr;
```

Here is the live code: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-leftpad-2jl5w

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot the difference than an answer. What did you change? Why should it solve the problem?

Comment: @Quentin   The user code is working fine, and I Just trring to convey those files should be in the same folder... but i did understand that  why your are down voted my answer...   kindly change it.

Answer (score -2):

Try to do this :

```
const { myfun, myStr } = require('./module1');
```

This should be work.

Comment: If they can't read the module, then they can't get the object returned by it, so they won't be able to destructure that object.

Comment: Hi @Rubs019, try to explain more about your answer. Try to explain why this will work as an example

Comment: My bad, I tried the solution and it's work for me. With and without the destructuration. I think the problem comes from the file structure.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion . Yes , the problem comes with file structure probably , as both files weren't in root folder .